# Download MySql Results as CSV & Special chars

Tags: php

I have a script that downloads results from a MySql table into an CSV file like so

```
$result = $sql2;
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
$headers = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
$headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i);
}
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
fputcsv($fp, $headers);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
}
die;
}
```

Which works fine, the problem i am having is some of the values of columns contain & quot;. When printing this data on to the web page it shows as a real quote " but when downloading it into the CSV it prints as & quote;. I have tried to htmlspecialchars_decode() but the problem is still there.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Consider using PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function rather than a badly-written homebrew.... the built-in function handles enclosures correctly

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: That is _not_ an "Excel file" you create, not even a spreadsheet document, it is simply a "tab separated value" text file, something similar as CSV. It would make sense to use phps CSV generating feature as mentioned by @MarkBaker above.

Comment: @MarkBaker I have edited my post with new CSV function